# SQL Report Builder Tablix split between pages

Tags: reportbuilder3.0

I have a report created using SQL Server Report Builder. I'm not very familiar with this app so sorry if this doesn't make sense.

I have an invoice report that has a lot of Account Payable lines. Enough that it will take two pages to display everything since there is a header and other information about the account before the AP lines. When i run the report it looks fine, but then when I print it to a PDF it always puts the AP lines on the second page and leaves more than half of the first page blank.

How can I get this to start the AP lines on the first page and then split them when reaching the bottom of the page?

**EDIT**

I've tried going into the properties of the Tablix Row and changing the `KeepTogether` property to false. This did not work.

I tried adding a small space after each line in the AP lines section. This did not work and added a bunch of extra lines that I don't want.

I tried changing the `KeepTogether` property for the whole `Tablix` to False. This did not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out with some help from a coworker. There was a container, a `rectangle` that had to have the `KeepTogether` set to false. Now it all starts on the first page and only goes to a second page once that AP lines reach the bottom of the page.